# UItableviewcell background color while click

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

How to set a color to the entire cell which selected or checkmarked and reset to previous color while in unchecked in uitableview?I tried but it showing a background color for a sec.can any one please help me to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here I think you want to color your cell when selected and another color if unselected,leaving those selected cells with the previous color. So have an array states globally. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath :

```
if (![myMutableArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [myMutableArray addObject:indexPath]; 
}
else{
    [myMutableArray removeObject:indexPath];
}

[sampleTableView reloadData];
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
if ([myMutableArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: Please state precisely and accurately what you need to do and what have you used so that others might understand your situation.

Comment: You got my idea but i want to change the color if the cell is checkmarked and if the same cell uncheckmarked means it should be uncolored.in the above solution its not working .Please help @AJS

Answer (score 2):

In your header file make an object of NSIndexPath(let it be checkedIndexPath used here) and assign its property and synthesize it also.In your tableView's method cellForRowAtIndexPath use:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Now in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath use following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
    UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    uncheckCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor green];
}
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

}
```

Using this you will have your cell in red if selected and in green if unselected.

Comment: its working fine,But the problem is while unchecking the cell, green color appears only after the next cell too.And the same it way continues to other cells.what should i do?

Comment: I have posted another answer.See if it helps in what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the `UITableViewCell`

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.png"]]
```

and then on the click event the color will automatically change .

You can change the color of the selection by :-

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

For changing the textLabel color .

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: but it ony applies to cell back ground not to cell content,i tried with cell.contentview .its not working @Tejeshwar Gill

Comment: In my tableview cell i have only text @Tejeshwar Gill

Comment: What do you need to do?Please specify clearly.Do you want to change color of the selected cells or the selectionStyle of the cells and then reset again if unselected.Please get it more clear.

Comment: i want to change the cell color while im selecting the cell and if im click again in the cell the previous color should show.@AJS

Comment: Try this cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor BlueColor];

Comment: @Tejeshwar Gill but i want to change the Cell bgcolor(content) .